The bottom navigation view is a little high in Android
While I am taking Bottom Nav example from android studio new project templet, the view is perfect.
But if I create new project with 'Empty View Activity' and implementing Bottom Nav manually, the view is a little high.
From android templet
Created by me
I have created manually with all the same code as android bottom nav templet is providing.
navigationFragmentKtx = "2.8.4"
navigationUiKtx = "2.8.4"


androidx-navigation-fragment-ktx = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-fragment-ktx", version.ref = "navigationFragmentKtx" }
androidx-navigation-ui-ktx = { group = "androidx.navigation", name = "navigation-ui-ktx", version.ref = "navigationUiKtx" }


Above is the libraries and versions, same as android templet provides.
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.BottomNavByMe" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- <item name="colorPrimary">@color/my_dark_primary</item> -->

        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <!-- Status bar color. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->


    </style>
</resources>

This is theme.xml , both light and dark theme are same  as this
package com.example.bottomnavbyme

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.enableEdgeToEdge
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.ViewCompat
import androidx.core.view.WindowInsetsCompat
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupWithNavController
import com.example.bottomnavbyme.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
import androidx.navigation.ui.setupActionBarWithNavController

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContentView(binding.root)

        ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
            val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
            insets
        }

        val navView: BottomNavigationView = binding.navView

        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment_activity_main)
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(
            setOf(
                R.id.navigation_home, R.id.navigation_dashboard, R.id.navigation_notifications
            )
        )
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
        navView.setupWithNavController(navController)



    }
}

Above is MainActivity.kt

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:paddingTop="?attr/actionBarSize">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

and this is activity_main.xml
In this project, I have 3 fragments HomeFragment.kt, DashboardFragment.kt, and NotificationsFragment.kt
and their correspond fragment_home.xml, fragment_dashboard.xml, fragment_notifications.xml
not providing those because, layout contains only a single TextView, nothing special.
Some more info
compileSdk = 35
minSdk = 28
targetSdk = 35

You should remove the following lines of code from your Activity:
ViewCompat.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener(findViewById(R.id.main)) { v, insets ->
    val systemBars = insets.getInsets(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
    v.setPadding(systemBars.left, systemBars.top, systemBars.right, systemBars.bottom)
    insets
}

This adds additional insets to the root container. At the same time, the Bottom Navigation View has built-in handling of insets systembars

No, its not working.

@plasma I changed the answer

Yes, it worked. Thank you..

@plasma can you mark my answer as accepted?

I found out one more thing,
if the line below is removed from the example it also works,
enableEdgeToEdge()

And, it work better for the devices which have on screen navigation buttons (back, recent and home button)
